# MVC 5 Search multiple columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, search

I've been trying all day to adapt the following tutorial to search multiple columns.

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search.html

It works fine to search a single column.  My problem is that I'd like to search more than a single column for the keyword, everything I have tried has resulted in similar behaviour where the result is acting as an 'And' instead of an 'Or' operator (so if it appears in both columns it works, rather than being in either column).  I have tried 'case' statements 'if else' etc but my logic has let me down.  I like to search for presence in either column

My controller code

```
    public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        var ClipQry = from m in db.Incidents
                      orderby m.ClipName
                       select m.ClipName;

        var SearchResult = from LoopVar in db.Incidents
                     select LoopVar;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            SearchResult = SearchResult.Where(s => s.ClipName.Contains(searchString));
        }


        return View("Search", SearchResult);
    }
```

The View code

```
<form asp-controller="Incidents" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="SearchString" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
    </p>
</form>
```

I have tried things as follows but it only results in same behaviour of acting as an 'And' operator

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            SearchResult = SearchResult.Where(s => s.ClipName.Contains(searchString));
            SearchResult = SearchResult.Where(y => y.ClipKeywords.Contains(searchString));
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is doing filtering on the `ClipName` property first and assigning the result to `SearchResult` variable. Then in the second line you are doing the filter on the `ClipKeywords` property on the same result (`SearchResult`, which is the filtered result from the previous line). So effectively you are doing an **AND** here.

You can do **OR** in your where clause.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
   SearchResult = SearchResult
                 .Where(s => s.ClipName.Contains(searchString) 
                           ||s.ClipKeywords.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Shyju, I was really struggling with the logic.  Your help is really appreciated :)